# Given $a<b$, find a sequence $x_n$ which converges to $a$ and $a<x_n<b$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Given two real numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a<b$, can we find a sequence $x_n$ which converges to $a$ and satisfies $a<x_n<b$?

I think we can use the Archimedean property but this will only give me a natural number bigger than $a$.

Comment: Let $x_n=a+\frac{b-a}{n+1}$?

Comment: Sorry it should be bigger than a and less than b. But according to your idea then could it be the constant sequence (a+b)/2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the sequence ${x_n}$ where $x_0=\frac{a+b}{2}$ and $x_{n+1}=\frac{a+x_n}{2}$

If $a<x_n<b$ then,
$$a=\frac{a+a}{2}<x_{n+1}=\frac{a+x_n}{2}<\frac{a+b}{2}<b$$
I will leave it to you to prove that it indeed converges to $a$

Comment: Thanks for answering. And applying your idea can I also say that if $x<x_n$ then $f(x)<f(x_n)$?

Comment: No that would depend on the function $f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $a+1/n$ and start the sequence at big enough $n$ so that every term lays in $(a,b)$.